# Warning while deleting model with no model associated

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.4

Hi all and thanks for you help

I have model structure as follows:

```
Class Model1 {
      public $hasMany = array(
            "Model2" => array (
            "className" => "Model2",
            "foreignKey" => "model1_id",
            "dependent" => TRUE
        )
}
```

Later on when I try to delete a given Model1 object, if it does not have any Model2 object associated yet, operation outputs a warning telling me that

```
Invalid argument supplied for foreach() [CORE\Cake\Model\Model.php, line 2648]
```

Is there any way of avoiding this warning message? I am requesting deletions through JSON AJAX requests and that response is just HTML, avoiding my JSON parser to process it correctly.

Comment: what's your delete function , can u show it plz !

Comment: As a first step I'd suggest to try it with the latest CakePHP version to check if this is maybe a bug that has been fixed. Also for debugging purposes check what exactly is being passed to the `foreach` statement. ps, please always mention your _exact_ CakePHP version!

Comment: @maysaghira it is the default CakePHP Model call, it is not customized any way

Comment: @ndm It is CakePHP 2.4.4, I am not iterating over the model my self, it is the cascade implementation in CakePHP who is doing it.

Comment: I know it's the core Model class doing that, my suggestion stands, debug the value, test against the latest version :)

Answer (score 1):

Fixed.

There was an afterFind callback in Model2 that was not returning the results of the query and was returning boolean TRUE instead.

Once this was fixed all started to work

Thanks @maysaghira and @ndm